# In TSQL, will the following examples yield different results?

Tags: t-sql, optimization, isnull

I have to change an update query in TSQL to include the following code:

```
(uh.FirstName != cu.FirstName or isnull(uh.FirstName,'|||') != isnull(cu.Firstname,'|||')
```

But to my mind that seems redundant and it would be better to just use the second part:

```
isnull(uh.FirstName,'|||') != isnull(cu.Firstname,'|||')
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ISNULL(x,'|||') is just trying to handle considering nulls equivalent. You have to handle each null case and potentially double null depending on whether that is a "match" or not. Here's my suggestion with the commented line being option depending on how you want to handle double null.

```
(
    uh.FirstName != cu.FirstName 
        OR uh.FirstName IS NULL AND cu.FirstName IS NOT NULL
        OR uh.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND cur.FirstName IS NULL
        --OR uh.FirstName IS NULL AND cur.FirstName IS NULL
)
```

. Not sure whether the coalesce is faster than substitution and comparison but my guess is it would be. It also doesn't allow for ambiguity comparing '|||' to NULL which would yield false results with that solution.

*Fixed after HABO's comment

Comment: Isn't the equivalent logic `... COALESCE(uh.FirstName,cu.FirstName) IS NOT NULL`, i.e. it is checking that the `FirstName` columns are not _both_ NULL?

Comment: whoops! Good catch I was coding for equivalency not unequivalency in the NULL handling. COALESCE won't shortcut the double null check in that case and you just have to code both extra cases which is a little more annoying. I.E. a != a OR coalesce(a,a) is not null would return true because the coalesce isn't null even though they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect any of the columns to actually contains the literal string value of three pipes (`'|||'`), you can use the second code snippet safely.

Quick demo:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    c1 varchar(5),
    c2 varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('a', 'a'), 
('a', 'b'), 
('a', null), 
(null, 'a'), 
(null, null), 
('b', 'a');


SELECT *, 'First' as example
FROM @T
WHERE c1 != c2 OR ISNULL(c1, '|||') != ISNULL(c2, '|||')

SELECT *, 'Second' as example
FROM @T
WHERE ISNULL(c1, '|||') != ISNULL(c2, '|||')
```

Results:

```
c1      c2      example
a       b       First
a       NULL    First
NULL    a       First
b       a       First

c1      c2      example
a       b       Second
a       NULL    Second
NULL    a       Second
b       a       Second
```